# VBA Excel Optimization for ForLoop

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone can help me to look for a good way to optimise this code into shorter lines? Do give me good suggestion.

```
With Selection
                .Value = "Apple"
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(1).Value = "Orange"
                .Offset(1).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(2).Value = "Strawberry"
                .Offset(2).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(3).Value = "Pear"
                .Offset(3).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(4).Value = "Pineapple"
                .Offset(4).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(5).Value = "Grape"
                .Offset(5).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(6).Value = "Banana"
                .Offset(6).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(8).Value = "Durian"
                .Offset(8).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(8, 1).Value = "Rambutan"
                .Offset(8, 1).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(8, 2).Value = "Dragonfruit"
                .Offset(8, 2).Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(8, 3).Value = "Mango"
                .Offset(8, 3).Font.Bold = True
            End With
```

Comment: If you have no errors or specific 'how to' questions then optimization questions are better suited for the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a source array for your fruits.

```
Dim fruits
fruits = Array("Apple", "Orange", ... , "Mango")
```

Then use a Loop to assign values to Range.
You'll need additional variables for it.

```
Dim n As Long, fruit

With Selection: n = 0
    For Each fruit In fruits
        .Offset(n) = fruit: n = n + 1
    Next
    .Resize(n + 1).Font.Bold = True '~~> format in one go
End With
```

I don't know if you'll consider this optimized enough but HTH.
Btw, I did not consider the shift in Column when you're assigning the fruit *Rambutan*.
I leave it to you. It may require another variable and *IF statement*.

Comment: There might have been a typo in the OP's sample data but the eighth row (e.g. `.OFFSET(7)`) was skipped as well.

Comment: @pnuts what I addressed is for the OP's short lines request. :) Also, I leave it up to him.

Comment: @Jeeped Yep. That as well. If this route is favorable is up to him/her.